# 3 models connected in rails find over the 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dataset, rails-activerecord

We have 3 models model1, model2, model3. This 3 are connect with

```
class Model1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :model2s
end
class Model2 < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :model1s
  has_many :model3s
end
class Model3 < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :model2s
end
```

In the table of Model1 exists id.

In the table of Model2 exists id and model1_id.

In the table of Model3 exists id and model2_id.

Now i want to get Data from the table1 and table2 out of Model3Controller.
This works fine.

```
class Model3Controller < ApplicationController
  def create
    @model2controller = Model2.find(params[:model3controller][:model2_id])
    @model1controller = ?
  end
end
```

How do we get data from the associated dataset from the table1 of the model1controller? Did we have to add the model1_id into the table3, or can we call it on an other way. Like this pseudocode

```
@model1controller = Model1.find(
params[:model3controller][:model2_id]params[:model2controller][:model1_id])
```

Comment: please take a look at [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html). I think it explains really well what you're trying to achieve..

Comment: I found a bug: belongs_to is always singular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be missing something, but it looks like you should only do the following:

```
model1 = Model3.find_by_id(params[:model3_id]).model2.model1
```

**Edit**. The above code works just like the following lines:

```
model3 = Model3.find_by_id(params[:model3_id]) # instantiate a model3

model2 = model3.model2 # from mode3 grab a model2
                       # this is possible due to the fact that model3 is associated with model2 via the belongs_to relation

model1 = model2.model1 # model2 "belongs_to" model1, i.e. we can grab model1 by asking model2: "whom do belong to?" just like in the previous example
```

**Please note** that accessing methods on instance is done calling in lowercase, i.e.

```
object.method # => something is returned
```

In your example you make mistake, calling `Model3.find_by_id(params[:id]).Model2` (notice the capital letter in `Model2`, which is wrong)

Also, check if params[:id] are actually being passed to the controller action. Otherwise, if it's absent, `Model3.find_by_id(params[:id])` will return `nil` and thus a mentioned error will be raised.

Comment: This gives me an error ` @model1controller = Model3.find_by_id(params[:id]).Model2.Model1`  undefined method `Model2' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Can you explain me the background of your Answer?

Comment: now i call in lowcase but get an new error `@model1= model3.find_by_id(params[:id]).model2.model1` `undefined local variable or method `model3' for #<Model3Controller:0x007fdf0c004e28>`

Comment: Why does'nt run this code? `@model1 = model3.find_by_id(params[:model3controller][:id]).model2.model1` The `:id` is passed. The error is this `undefined method `model2' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: from the error you're getting it seems that `model3.find_by_id(params[:model3controller][:id])` finds no `model3`. how do you pass `:id`? double check you're actually nesting  it under `:model3controller` in params. try looking into the development logs to see how exactly `id` is being passed inside the controller/method. Also, double check if the model3 with a given `id` is present in the database

Comment: I'm going right that `:id` is the id of model3? Yes! Is id is filled in the db. If i print out `<%=@model3.id%>` in a view i see the acctual id. But why isn't there in the logs? I also find the model2.id. My Question is now. Im trying to search with the id of the entry in model3 in model2 and model1. But the ids are not the same. e. g. the `:id` of model3.id is 1 then is it not necessary that the `model2.id` is also 1. So if i search over the model3.id into the other models with this value is it not sure that i found something. I have a thinking mistake?

Comment: Ids of `model2` and `model1` are not important (and shouldn't be the same -- as they are different tables!) as long as they are "connected" to each other. So having `model3` instance you should check if it has 'model2_id' field on it, in order to be able to access `model2` instance via `model3.model2` call;

Comment: Have you watched the basic "Blog in 15 minues using Rails"? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tUH1hewXnC0 You might want to read Rails Guides also to get some better understanding of ActiveRecord associations: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

Comment: Thanks for the tipp i know my problem. I will write my controller again, maybe without scaffolding